# Why “frame of reference” can apparently mean two different things?

Tags: reference-frames, coordinate-systems, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

(Originally posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4023330/516814), but apparently it is suitable for physics SE) There are several things about frame of reference in physics which I know.

1. We may work in $\mathbb R^3,$ but this set is annoying because it has an origin. In physics we wish to have a decentralized theory where laws are independent of the choice of origin, so we would instead work on a (Riemannian) manifold $M$ with a metric $g.$
2. A **frame of reference** means a one-parameter subgroup $\phi_t$ of the group of isometries of $M$. This should be **different** from the concept of a **local coordinate frame** of a manifold, which is also called a "frame" for some reason.
3. The above idea can be generalised. See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_frame#Method_of_the_moving_frame).
4. **However,** the first sentence in [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_of_reference) says that a frame is a coordinate system with reference points. **This definition is also very commonly seen in many books.**

So, we end up with two definitions of frames of reference: (by vector I mean either tangent vector of a manifold, or simply a vector in $\mathbb R^n$)

1. **The one-parameter subgroup version.** A frame of reference is (at least in the definition) **not** a set of coordinates, but a function/an action of a Lie group that dictates how old points are changed into new ones in new frame.
2. **The coordinate version.** A frame of reference is a system of coordinates that describes the system. Saying that it is **a change of coordinates** in some way implies that (tangent) vectors/points **themselves** should be **"independent" of the coordinate/frame in some sense** (not always "independent" - the acceleration vector in rotating frame is different from that in an inertial frame). This is very different from the first definition, where vectors **themselves** are changed.

**So, why do we have two very different meanings for "frame of reference"?** In practical application of frames, we never seem to run into this problem.

Comment: Because physicists are not always totally consistent and sometimes use the same term to mean different things ? Anyway, the two definitions do not seem so *very* different - one is a more dynamic version of the other.

Comment: @gandalf61, the question the OP is asking then is *why* do they employ *inconsistent* meanings? The tenor of your remark appears to suggest it isn't pertinent to have asked this, and also conflates *ambiguous* terminology (i.e. terminology that has an unclear meaning), with these explicitly inconsistent meanings (the difference between which the OP has successfully articulated).

Comment: @Steve Yes, I don't think there is much point asking questions that amount to "why are things the way they are when it would be better if they were otherwise". And I am not convinced that the two definitions are so very different from one another. But I agree this is not an answer to the OP's question, which is why I posted it as a comment. Feel free to write your own answer if you think that the question can be answered.

Comment: @gandalf61, if you think they are truly equivalent then that itself would be an answer. I'm not in a position to adjudicate on the content of the OP's question myself, only to address claims like "I don't think there's much point asking why things are the way they are". It's perfectly appropriate for a learner to ask why there are two (seemingly) inconsistent definitions employed - not least because having a multiplicity of concepts, if just one will do, adds to the burden of reproducing knowledge of physical science. And if just one *won't* do, then why?

Comment: @gandalf61 Even if you disagree that they are very different, you probably agree that they are different. The difference might not be physically significant, but it is certainly mathematically very significant.